# How achieve auto-numbering in R?

Tags: r

This is very elementary for those who use R... (But I do stats with Stata and Mplus.)

I develop many plots (638 in total) and want to save all in separate files. It worked well first, not now

```
for(i in 001:638){ 
## command for plot comes here, including mentioning of i ##
    dev.copy(png,'plot-%d.png')
    dev.off()
}
```

I want one file for each plot, but end up with a single plot file (plot_1.png), with only the last plot.

Christopher

Answer (score 2):

`png` function will do this by default.  For example, this will create 10 plots in your working directory.

```
png("plot-%d.png")
for(i in 1:10) plot(1:i)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Assume this refers to autonumbering. Thanks, will look into this as an alternative option.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea! Note to OP, you can use C-style numbering so `png("plot-%03d.png")` will output 3-digit numbers with 0's for padding, 001, 002, ...

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use one of the paste() functions to create your string.

Since you didn't provide a reproducible example I can only guess, but I think that something like this would probably work.

```
paste("plot",i,".png", sep = "")
```

in place of your current use of c style % replacement. So this

```
for(i in 001:638){ 
#command for plot comes here, including mentioning of i ##
dev.copy(png,paste("plot",i,".png", sep = ""))
dev.off()
```

}